# Deploy installed extensions on magento 2 live

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento 2 extension on local so now I want to deploy it on live server. I have made some changes in it aswell. So what is best way to do that ? just copy code there and run deploy command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to upload your code and Run Following Commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Thanks